# Jmeter: How to reuse custom java function between different JMX file

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, custom-function, jmeter-3.2

**Requirement**: Post response time of every sampler to Mongo DB, for that created an HttpClient java code(Class function).

**Problem**: Need to call the custom (reuse same code between 150+ jmx file) Java function to be called from Beanshell after every sampler.

```
void logTransaction(responseTime,samplerName);
```

**Solution need**: Incorporate custom java function(.c or .txt) with jmx file.

For example in Load runner we can include .h file(shared in common path) with  reusable code and include in globals.h.

Is there any method or solution available with jmeter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Code can be reusable by saving in a java file and give the file path in JSR223.

Answer (score 2):

You can run same script file in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which support also Java/Beanshell languages.

Put in `Script file` field the script file name and e
reuse it in different jmx files

Answer (score 1):

Create a JAR that contains your reusable java code and call it from JSR223 Listener checking "Cache compiled script if available".

[image: JSR223 Listener]

Code your call using default scripting language (Groovy):

```
def yourInstanceClass = new YourClass()
yourInstanceClass.logTransation(sampleResult.getTime(), sampleResult. getSampleLabel());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   beanshell.sampler.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc
   ```
2. Put your `logTransaction` function in the *BeanShellSampler.bshrc* file (same location, JMeter's "bin" folder)
3. Next time you start JMeter you will be able to call the function from any [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) in any script

References:

- [Confifuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)